# Windows crashes after new RAM added, possibly incompatible RAM

Tags: windows-10, memory, crash, desktop-computer, compatibility

I had 8GB of DDR4 2133 RAM, I added a new 8GB RAM unit of the same type just different manufacturer. 
When both RAMs are installed my computer crashes randomly every 10-30 mins. 
I looked for solutions online with no help. I tried to start the computer with just the new RAM unit installed - it crashes almost immediately. 
I managed to take a screenshot of CPU-Z Memory in all 3 situations:

My comp with just the old RAM unit:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVnEo.jpg

My comp with just the new RAM unit:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSL8Z.jpg

My comp with both RAMs:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yUNg.jpg

I don't know much about memory but I can see that NB frequency and number of clocks is different.

The new problematic RAM unit:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/HyperX-HX421C14FB2-8-FURY-DDR4...

My system specs:
Win 10
i7-6700
ASRock H110M-HDV

Is it possible that the new RAM is incompatible with motherboard/CPU even though it's the same type and everything?
Or maybe I need to tune the frequency in BIOS or something? Please help

Comment: Does memtest86+ (part of most Linux distros) say any of your memory is bad?

Comment: I would suspect a faulty RAM-module first (most likely the new one). I would first run a test software (there are plenty free ones, even the BIOS does a basic RAM check usually a "quick" and a "full" one, depending on the setting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even the two identical memories may be incompatible for a machine. Based on your description and screenshot of CPU-Z, maybe the new RAM is incompatible with motherboard, and the new memory causes the North Bridge frequency to be too high. So when you start the computer with just the new RAM unit installed, it crashes.